# mysql_connect() fails with empty warning

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of setting up PHP / MYSQL on a Windows Server 2003 machine, with IIS.  I have installed PHP 5.3.8 and MySQL 5.5.  PHP is configured to use FastCGI.

In `php.ini` I have the following lines uncommented:

`extension=php_mysql.dll`

`extension=php_mysqli.dll`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","test");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: $php_errormsg' . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(). "\n");
  }
echo "connected"; 
?>
```

Here is the output:

`PHP Warning:  mysql_connect():  in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysqltest.php on line 2`

I can connect to the MYSQL database on this server from a PHP page running on another webserver - so I know that my MYSQL database is correctly accepting connections.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It doesn't seem to even reach the line with your error message. Are you using a custom error handler?

Comment: I am unsure how to implement a custom error handler - how would I check to see if one is in place?

Comment: Can you connect manually through a mysql client tool? Also your die message will not interpolate the $php_errormsg variable because you have it in single quotes

Comment: @gnub if above is your full code, then you're not using one. Really strange.

Comment: @Pekka , the above is m full code.

Comment: @Cfreak Yes, I can connect manually through the mysql client tool.  I changed the quotes to double quotes.  The output remains the same.

Comment: Try `$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "test") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @Grexis: Here is the result: `PHP Warning:  mysql_connect():  in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysqltest.php on line 2`

Comment: Are those php .dlls specifically compiled for your PHP version? Mixing/matching different api versions isn't good.

Comment: Try using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Also, does your php error log have any more information? Is your firewall configured to allow outbound/inbound access correctly?

Comment: @MarcB They are the dll's that installed with PHP.  When I check the details, they says the version is `5.3.8.0`, which matches my version of PHP

Comment: @Grexis My php error log is empty.  The Windows Firewall / Intenet Connection Sharing service is not running.  I have Symantec Endpoint Protection.  It is configured not to touch network traffic.

Results from using `localhost`:
`PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysqltest.php on line 2`

`PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysqltest.php on line 2`

Comment: `PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysqltest.php on line 2`

Comment: I can connect to the MYSQL database on this server from a PHP page running on another webserver - so I know that my MYSQL database is correctly accepting connections.

Comment: I had a permissions issue with my log file - the user account that IIS was using did not have write permission.  I remedied that, and now I'm getting output in my log file.  It's not any more descriptive, but at least its recording it .... `PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]:  in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysqltest.php on line 2
`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently I had a  permissions issue. I was able to resolve it by following these steps:

From Windows Explorer, I...

- right-clicked on C:\Inetpub
- went to Properties > Security > Permissions
- selected "Replace permission entries on all child objects with entries shown here that apply to child objects"
- clicked Apply
- restarted IIS by running `iisreset` from a command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

To view your connection error, you can print the output of `mysql_error`.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","test") or die('cannot connect : '. mysql_error());
```